# Converting patches of a binary tensor to decimal in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to convert patches of a binary matrix into a decimal matrix with the same shape in TensorFlow. More explicitly,

- Input: A binary `H x L` matrix `A`
- Ouput: An integer matrix `X` such that `X[i,j] = decimal(A[i,(j-k/2):(j+k/2)])`. That is for each element of the output it takes a `1xk` patch of `A` and converts it to its decimal representation with zero-padding.
- Computational Considerations: `k` is typically quite large (i.e. 16) and `H x L = 32*400`. Thus, expanding anything in terms of `2**k` is computationally infeasible.

**Example**

```
A = [[1,1,0,1,0,1],
     [1,0,1,0,0,0]]
k = 3
X = [[3,6,5,2,5,2],
     [2,5,2,4,0,0]]
```

**Naive Solution**

```
# Compute all possible binary substrings
rows = []
for i in range(2**k):
    binary = bin(i)[2:].zfill(k)
    row = np.array(map(float, list(binary)))
    rows.append(row)
W = tf.transpose(tf.to_float(tf.stack(rows))) # K x 2^K
W = tf.expand_dims(W,0) # 1 x K x 2^K

# Extract the indicator values via convolution
X = tf.nn.conv2d(A, W, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME') # H x L x 2^K

# Collapse to find the decimal value
X = tf.argmax(X, axis = 2) # H x L
```

However, the convolution approach forces you to define a tensor with shape `H x L x 2^K`. Is there a good computationally efficient way to do this in tensorflow without this?